# How to return a value, but continue a loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller, future, callable

I apologize if there's already an answer to my question, but I couldn't find a solution. I want to make an application which basically has two text fields and two combo boxes where you choose a increment step, and when you click start you can see the numbers change in different steps in each text box every second. I managed to do it in a single file using two threads, but I want to do it the MVC way. In other words, I have a `Controller` class which handles the `View` click, and runs a thread from my `Model` class, which returns the value on every iteration of the loop, and then I pass that value to the `JTextField.setText()` method to visualize it. In a single class I can easily do it in the loop itself:

```
while(!isInterrupted()){
            count += step;
            textField1.setText(count);
            sleep(1000);
}
```

However, I think there are two ways to do it. Pass a reference of the View to the Model, and manipulate the text field from the `Model` class, which I feel counters the idea of the MVC to separate the model and the view. Or use a `Callable` or a `Future` somehow (I don't really know how they work, and if they will work in my case) to pass the `count` value on every iteration of the `while` loop to the `Controller`, which in turn is going to pass it on to the `View`.

How do you think I should do it, and is there any other (better) way of doing it?

Comment: "Pass a reference of the View to the Model, and manipulate the text field from the Model class" - thus breaking MVC ... aside from manipulating GUI from a NON-GUI Thread. Android won't let you even compile that. **You need a [Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).**

Comment: Could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on Event Handling in Java and Listeners.

The basic gist is: You want your GUI to be updated. More specific - you want it to be notified, when to update itself.

Solution : Listeners.

What's that? I linked to the oracle lesson in my comment, but basically you "register" your gui to be notified of some sort of event at the model. That is done by providing some Interface, that your gui will implement - for example an interface that declares a method 'onMyValueChanged( int oldVal, int newVal )'. You will then add a reference to the gui at the model. The model would then use that reference to call the Listener interface when appropriate.

Mind that you should manipulate GUI Elements from the GUI-Thread (aka "EDT" = "Event Dispatch Thread"), only. So you will probably have to do some inter-thread communication in the listener implementation.

A convenient means of doing all the above is using [SwingPropertyChangeSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/SwingPropertyChangeSupport.html). See [How to write a PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) for examples and further explanation.

Another way of meeting your requirement would be to use a SwingWorker and publish changes in the process. A good starting point would be this tutorial from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

And this section about the EDT is definitely for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

As a sidenote, I can really recommend those Oracle Lessons. They are an informative read and they are free. They really helped me a lot when I was a beginner and they still do frequently as look-up for things I do not use frequently.